# Check if an element is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JS array of objects like this:

```
Ident: "2"
Text: "Foo"
```

Now I want to check if the object with the `Ident` equal to `2` is in the array. How can I do this? It's not possible with `jQuery.inArray` because I don't have the whole object, just the `Ident`.

Comment: A regular loop should work fine. If you check the values a lot it makes sense to create a new object (with the data as keys) to cache it (see [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-obj/20)). What have you tried?

Comment: Are you working with an `array` of objects? Or with an `object` that serves as associate array?

Comment: There's a `find` function in ES6 and it's supported by some browsers. [A polyfill is available.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will indeed have to do the loop the long way here:

```
function findByIdent(array, ident) {
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].Ident === ident) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1; // not found
}
```

If it's any consolation, this used to be the way *all* is-this-element-in-this-array calls were done!

Note that this presumes that you have an array that looks approximately like this:

```
[{Ident: "2", Text: "foo"}, {Ident: "3", Text: "bar"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

As you had mentioned JQuery, you can use "grep" method:

```
 if (jQuery.grep(arr, function( n ) {
   return ( n.Ident == "2" );
 }).length)
 ...
```

but it will loop through all elements.

Comment: Yes, if you're looking for `true`/`false` rather than the index, that's a  nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var found = false;
for (var i =0;i<somearray.length;i++) {
    if (somearray[i].Ident === 2) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```